# Cannot login after installation like service AranangoDB Windows7

Tags: authentication, arangodb

I looked at the config files everything is fine, made environment variables PATH's, started and restarted the service put in the right password, searched for someone with similar problems(not found).
Every time i go to the default location via browser I get the login screen but when i put in 'root' and the password I get an error message 'Login Failed'.
When I set `athenticate=false` in the conf file i can access the web manager.

Anybody know how to solve this or at least what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you try the following: set authenticate to false. Access the UI, create a new user "test", give access to the _system database. Shutdown and change authenticate to true. Can you log in with the new user?

Comment: Yep, worked like a charm, what's the catch is it a bug or a standard feature it seems kinda odd?

Comment: Ok, so there is no principle problem. Maybe the "root" password was mixup during install. Best report this as an issue in github with all the necessary information (exe or zip, where exactly the password was entered during install).

Comment: Also I see now i've forgot to mention, now i can log in with the root too.

Comment: This bloody thing is so complicated. I wonder why is it so hard for developers to think about user experience at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the installation, the ArangoDB Installer will ask you the password for the administrator user.

Use `root` as user name with your `password` to gain access to the database.

Open a CMD-Window in your ArangoDB installation directory.

To re-gain access to the database, stop the ArangoDB database service using

```
sc stop ArangoDB
```

after the database was stopped, invoke

```
.\usr\bin\arango-secure-installation
```

which will ask you for a new password.

After that, start the service again using:

```
sc start ArangoDB
```